# Java program to read information from a website

Tags: java, parsing

I am writing a program in Java that will help track a "Fantasy College Basketball" league for my friends. I am struggling with finding the best implementation to automatically update the statistics for each player drafted.

As some background, every day individuals in the fantasy league earn points based on statistics that college basketball players they drafted earned that week. Right now, I do this mannually:

*1: Go to a player's ESPN profile*

ESPN tracks individual player stats with a URL that is based on a random and unique player ID number. Frank Kaminsky's ID is 56759, so his ESPN profile is: http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/player/_/id/56769/. We can assume that the user will input a player's ESPN ID when the player is drafted and we will have that information when updating stats.

*2: Parse HTML page to get relevant stats*

Looking at the URL above - the important information is in the "2014 - 2015 Game Log" section. I would want to obtain the most recent game's PTS, REB, AST, BLK, STL, PF, and TO to use elsewhere in my program.

**What is the best approach to this?**

My first reaction was to use a .openStream() on a URL, but this would require a lot of careful string parsing. The HTML really isn't pretty line by line...

I have heard of jsoup, but haven't used it ever before. If people here think that is the best way to proceed, I'd be happy to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jsoup, it is easy to learn and made for the job.

The JSoup website has a nice tutorial on it.

Have a look here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url

Then parse your document with the methods explained here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend http://www.seleniumhq.org/ 
This is an external library but it is really easy to use and learn. Normally it is used to test websites but it is really multi-purposed.

```
Driver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://yoursitehere.iamnotarealsite");
```

That would be the code to open a chrome browser and to navigate to your site. To find elements you can do things like:

```
WebElement stats=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#statsOrSomething"));
```

And you can use standard get text functions on WebElements:

```
stats.getText();//Gets players stats
```

Also did I mention that it has many language bindings including Java? Also: I don't work for selenium or its parent company so this is not a shameless plug.